# Как работает функция componentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я только изучаю React, и не могу понять поведение данной функции. Допустим, у меня имеется 2 компонента: родительский и дочерний.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.value = '';
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
  
        <input onChange={(e) => {
          this.value = e.target.value
        }}></input>
        <button onClick={() => {
          this.setState({value: this.value})
        }}>Send</button>
  
      {this.state && <Child newValue={this.state.value}/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.value = null;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('prevState')
    console.log(prevState);
    console.log('this.state')
    console.log(this.state)
    if (prevState === this.state) {
      this.setState({value: this.props.newValue})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello!
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

При нажатии на button родительский компонент обновляет своё состояние и повторно рендерид дочерний компонент. Но я совершенно не понимаю, почему здесь для корректной работы выполняется условие (prevState === this.state), а не (prevState !== this.state). Выводы из консоли:

```js
// я ввёл в поле инпут единицу и нажал два раза button
// так как в первый раз дочерний элемент только монтируется, 
// а обновляется только при втором нажатии
prevState
null
this.state
null
prevState
null
this.state
{value: "1"}

// эти выводы покажутся, если я введу 12 и нажму button
prevState  
{value: "1"}  // почему здесь выводится значение {value: "1"}, а не null? 
              // Ведь изменение состояния не было.
this.state
{value: "1"}
prevState
{value: "1"}
this.state
{value: "12"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каждый раз при срабатывании рендер разделяет версии состояний и пропсов на текущие и предыдущие. Соответственно, если setState срабатывает внутри componenDidUpdate дочернего элемента в следующий раз после обновления компонента, в этой функции prevState !== this.state.

После же обновления компонента в связи с изменением состояния его предка, componentDidUpdate получит prevState === this.state, так как прямого вызова this.setState внутри дочернего компонента не было.